# Why do we need to open a file to upload it to Azure Blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk

I'm new to Azure and am trying to upload files (in tens of thousands) to Azure blob storage using their Python SDK. All examples that I came across on the web open a file before uploading it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-python#uploading-a-blob

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python#upload-a-block-blob-from-a-local-file-path

Why is this necessary? I am concerned that if this will slow down the upload.

Boto3 for AWS S3 doesn't do this. Can you please explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you share the link to the examples you referenced?

Comment: @GauravMantri I edited the question's description to add a link

Comment: @soodankit Opening a file before uploading it to Azure Blob storage is necessary because the SDK requires a file stream to upload the file. The file stream allows the SDK to read the file in chunks, which is more efficient than reading the entire file into memory before uploading it. This is why all the examples you found on the web open a file before uploading it. While it may seem like this would slow down the upload, it actually makes it faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this necessary? I am concerned that if this slows down the upload.

To upload data, the Azure Blob Storage client libraries need a **`file-like`** object.

Large files can be uploaded quickly because the file is read in **`chunks`**. Opening a file before uploading it does not necessarily slow down the upload process. In fact, it can be more efficient to read data from a file-like object than to read it from a file on disk.

**Code:**

```
with open("./SampleSource.txt", "rb") as data: 
  blob.upload_blob(data)
```

The above code opens the file, creates a file-like object, and uploads the contents of the file-like object to the blob storage.

The same process applies when using Boto3 for uploading to AWS S3 - you can use a file object for the upload by **`upload_fileobj`**.

**Code:**

```
with open('filename', 'rb') as data:
    s3.upload_fileobj(data, 'mybucket', 'mykey')
```

**Reference:**

[Uploading files - Boto3 1.34.64 documentation (amazonaws.com)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Venkatesan. I have 2 doubts:
1. We can upload to s3 without opening the file as well:

s3.upload_file(Filename=src, Bucket=s3_bucketname, Key=dest)

is something similar possible in Azure blob storage?

2. What if the file were encoded or password-protected? How will the option to open the file to upload work?

Comment: In Azure blob storage with open is the only way, regarding 2nd question if the file is encoded or password-protected, you would need to open the file and decode or decrypt  using gpg it before uploading it to Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: You can able to upload the encrypted(password protection ) file for reading the file you can use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78155327/error-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-storagestreamdownloader/78158907#78158907 to decrypt the file.